# What happens when many clients access the same websocket server simultaneously?

Tags: websocket

I built a simple websocket server using the [Python websockets package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets).
I also built a client in HTML+Javascript. It works fine and I want to open it to the public.

Since I am new to websockets, I am not sure what is going to happen when many people access the websocket server simultaneously:

- Does the websocket server keep a queue of incoming requests and handle them sequentially?
- If so, does the websocket client (the standard client in Javascript) waits indefinitely to a reply, or is there a timeout?

For example, if 200 users access the HTML page simultaneously, and each request takes 1 second to handle, what will the 200th user will see - will he just wait 200 seconds and see the usual reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what will the 200th user see? will he just wait 200 seconds and see the usual reply?

Surely not. Even in HTTP example, the server can usually handle some of the requests simultaneously. The number of requests that can be replied at the same time actually depends on many thing, specially your web-server (or application-server) configuration. Since each request usually takes a thread, they don't wait for each other to end. Unless there are too many connected threads in the thread-pool so the webserver has to wait to answer and close one, to begin processing the next request.

Only there is a slight difference in websockets. Unlike HTTP which is stateless and the connection closes right after the response is sent, Websockets are kept alive to interact with server. So if each socket takes a thread, still application server can handle their request and response simultaneously. But the big problem is about the size of the thread-pool.

If there are too many active connections, usually the new connection cant be made because the pool is full and unlike HTTP, there might not be an open space for new connection any time soon. Application server on this situation usually handles it by not accepting new connections.

To work around this problem you must have enough resources and you should find suitable configurations to handle as many as concurrent connections you need. I'm not a python developer, but in Java and Tomcat application server, this is usually done by a right configuration which increases the application server thread-pool size. You must find same kind of configuration in what ever application server you use.

**update**
To answer the question in comment, I add this update.

> So, suppose there are 10 threads in the pool and 11 users, what will the 11th user see when trying to connect?

If maximum session pool size is 10, the 11th connection usually can not be made. Depending on application server one of these scenarios might happen.

- Connection keeps waiting to connect till it reaches it's connect timeout.
- Server immediately drops the new connection with some status code. Sometimes the status code might be `503 service unavailable`.
- Its rare but server might even drop some in-active or idle connections from pool and accept the new connection.

Comment: So, suppose there are 10 threads in the pool and 11 users, what will the 11th user see when trying to connect?